# Windows 7 Domain users temporary profiles on netbooks

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles, active-directory

I have a bunch of users on a Windows 2008 Active Directory domain who are getting temporary profiles when logging on through netbook computers. When they log in to a desktop computer their profiles load up fine. Both the netbook and desktop computers are running Windows 7. What could cause certain computers to not load up a profile correctly?

Comment: How are the netbooks connected to the domain?  If wirelessly, have they had provisions made to ensure they connect to the wireless and locate the domain _before_ trying to log in?

Comment: They are wireless, and seem to connect fine whenever I test them, even logging in immediately after boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows workstations won't load a non-mandatory profile from a network that they consider to be slow. If it works on quicker machines but not on slower ones, that's what I'd check first. If it's important to have the profile load, there's some settings you can tweak to change Windows' definition of a slow network, and that should fix it. No more details, sorry, as I'm not near a Windows 7 machine at the moment.